# Show all posts in category

Tags: posts, categories, loop, archives, slug

I am trying to show all posts in each category. I've been searching around and it seems I need to have either the category `slug` or `term_id` to do so, like the code below.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=MyCategory&showposts=9999'); ?>
```

I'm currently editing the `archive.php` how to get the `slug` name?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks Michael, I was confuse that how to display category wise post on archive.php by query_post, because I am using Magic_fields plugin. really this script help me. Again thaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the category slug of the category archive:

```
$cat_slug = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->slug;
```

alternatively, to get the category ID of the category archive:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate you help! Just a question: do you know a better way to show all posts than `<?php query_posts('category_name=MyCategory&showposts=9999'); ?>` Thanks!

Comment: @Muazam `showposts` parameter is deprecated since 2.1, use `posts_per_page` with arg -1, also it would be better if you use array for `query_posts` args:

`<?php query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'my_category_slug', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>`

Comment: @Mamaduka One more question, do you know how to order the result by ID and DESC?

Comment: @Muazam add this two parameters:

`<?php query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'my_category_slug', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>`

Answer (score -1):

get all the categories from the database

```
$cats = get_categories();
```

// loop through the categries

```
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
```

setup the cateogory ID

```
$cat_id= $cat->term_id;
```

Make a header for the cateogry

```
echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";


query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=100");  
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category

```
<?php } ?>
```

done the foreach statement